# Sort by Similarity instead of Alphabetically

Tags: algorithm, sorting, conventions

Sorting alphabetically, such as with `sorted()` in Python would yield the following:

`a
ab
aa
aab`

How might one go about achieving the following instead?

`a
aa
ab
aab`

More specifically, is there a conventional word for this, or is it otherwise a matter of implementing a custom algorithm to do so?

Comment: You haven't specified what language this is, so I don't know what `sorted` is. It definitely doesn't seem to be doing an alphabetical sort (since `ab` is before `aa`).

Comment: As others have said, your question is meaningless. Sorting is pretty simple. You _must_ decide on a _total order_ of the universe of elements. Then the sort arranges items in that order. A pairwise similarity measure alone is not enough to define a total order.

Comment: Specifically and precisely, what do you mean by "sorting by similarity"? Does the first list contain a mistake where "aa" and "ab" are accidentally transposed?

Comment: I was curious if there was some technical terminology that described or best practice that achieved the desired order, from an algorithmic perspective. It seems that there is no such thing, meaning that the answer to my ultimate question is affirmative. I can see how the question can come off as lacking specificity.

Comment: Your example does not provide enough information about the goal - would `a aa aab ab` be equivalent? (Just one character difference in neighbours, too). You may be looking for _clustering_.

Comment: @greybeard You're right, the problem is not adequately described. In your example that is definitely equivalent, although it would be unusual for any `aa` to appear before `a` when it was `a aa` beforehand. I've actually achieved my desired order with a clustering-type algorithm although I hoped that there was a specific or generalizable practice for doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on, among other things, programming language of your choosing. In, say, Java, you can use `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`, for which you pass a comparator that can do whategver you want it to do, like return the comparison value based on similarity. In other languages, or when implementing sorting algorithms yourself, you can just swap standard value comparison for your own methods.

That said, I still don't see what you mean by similarity. As far as I can see, you want to order the strings first by length, and then alphabetically wthin a given length. In this case, the `Comparator` you would have to pass to the method mentioned above would have to first compare the lengths, and if they're equal, the values of two strings.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array and create a new ArrayList.  Add to the array accordingly using [loopString.compare(previousString);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Make sure the strings are all in lower case or all in uppercase.
Since 'a' comes before 'b' it will do what you have asked.